# Word VBA superscript issue

Tags: vba, ms-word

I received a word document that I have to parse.  I am looping through the paragraph object (after I remove the tables) to get the formatted text.

For the most part this is working well except for the superscript formatting. I placed a debug.print....following...to discover something I thought was strange.

```
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
For Each Para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    Debug.Print Para.Range.Text
    Debug.Print Para.Range.FormattedText
Next
```

The output of my debug.print is as follows...both .text and .formattedtext..I have removed the duplicate lines.

```
kilo (k) 10³
centi (c) 10-2
milli (m) 10-³
micro (µ) 10-6
nano (n) 10-9
pico (p) 10-12
```

This is the strange part (for me).
The superscripts that worked, lines 1 and 3 have no discernible formatting but as you can see, the debug.print displays the desired format of the superscript.

The lines that did  not work, lines 2,4,5,6 are marked as superscript in the font properties of the document.

My question is how can I preserve the superscript formatting as it appears in the word document?  All of the lines in my document that should have superscript formatting appear correct in the document but when I try to read the paragraphs the lines that are formatted as superscript do not persist...the paragraphs that have the appearance of superscript but not the formatting codes come across as superscript.  This document is the product of a contracted team that I have been unable to contact.

The document can be downloaded at the following link.

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C636FDD587E837CB!517&authkey=!ADjgA8mlRJqvv6U&ithint=file%2cdoc

Thanks in advance for your help.

Anthony Jaxon, Los Angeles, USA

Comment: are you SURE those are regular chars with superscript font applied? `2` and `3` do have dedicated "superscript" glyphs in most fonts e.g. unicode U+00B2 and U+00B3.

Comment: If you're using debug.print the ones that appear superscripted are almost certainly special characters as Marc notes above. Formatting would not appear in the Immediate Window, but if you inserted those ranges in another Word document you would (presumably) see the superscripting.